# what does ElasticSearch unlike Solr designed from the ground up to be a distributed index mean?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, solr

In a talk, I heard that ElasticSearch

> Unlike Solr, was designed from the ground up to be a distributed index

I was wondering what that means by ElasticSearch designed from the ground up to be a distributed index?

What is Solr designed to be? How is the answer different from distributed index?

Answer (score 1):

The first versions of Solr did not support clustering - it didn't even support more than one core inside each instance of Solr. Multicore support was introduced later, then SolrCloud (the clustering support) and collections was introduced with Solr 4.

You did have manual clustering support (i.e. what's known as sharding) and replication support (first through external programs such as rsync, then built-in through http replication) before SolrCloud was introduced, but SolrCloud was the first version that supported it without explicit handling from your own code.